# Verify and Test Multiple orderer using Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have fabric with 3 orderers but the problem is when I stop the orderer container which runs on 7050 port, I can't make any transaction. It says me that "service unavailable" but when I stop another container (which is running on the port other than 7050) all works fine. What should be the reason behind this? I have checked logs of peer and orderers but there is nothing like an error. Can anyone please help me with this?

My network is with 1 peer, 1 CA and 3 orderers
I have 3 zookeepers and 4 Kafka brokers.

logs when I start the fabric:

```
1. peer logs: https://pastebin.com/hPhKu3QB
2. orderer0 logs: https://pastebin.com/57aYAeW2
3. orderer1 logs: https://pastebin.com/PzLKurE2
2. orderer2 logs: https://pastebin.com/5D4shcJN
```

Not all three orderer created is able to connect with the client but only the orderer which mapped by port 7050 is able to connect with the client. Rest of the two orderers is just running containers that don't seem to do anything. Just to make sure that Kafka cluster working properly we tried stopping the containers one by one and found that only one container is able to accept the transaction(by calling composer rest apis) and others are giving SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE error.

By tracing the log we found that these two failed containers are giving below warning while starting the fabric.

> 2018-06-25 09:53:23.723 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 4da
>   [channel: composerchannel] Rejecting deliver requestfor
>   172.18.0.14:37702 because of consenter error

Note: I am testing it using composer tool. I can also share the code if anyone can look into.

I hope it makes sense to your end. Let me know in case anything you would like to ask.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I think that as it stands at the moment, Composer uses Fabric Node SDK functions and connection profiles, and that only the first Orderer in the list in the connection.json is used. I'm not certain of this.

Comment: @RThatcher But in that case what is the meaning of using Kafka cluster? How even can decide if my Kafka setup is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can Configure Proxy behind the Orderer.
In my test case, I have used haproxy

### My haproxy-config:

```
 frontend HAPROXY
bind *:80
    mode tcp
    default_backend orderers
 backend orderers
    mode tcp
    stats enable
    balance roundrobin
    server orderer1 Orderer1-IP:Orderer1-PORT check
    server orderer2 Orderer2-IP:Orderer2-PORT check
    server orderer3 Orderer3-IP:<Orderer3-PORT check
```

Finally,
You have to use only Haproxy URL in your connection-profile.json

Now You can check Orderer Failover.